# set system date and time within c++ program in linux

Tags: c++, linux, date, time

In my program user selects date and time in an extjs form and then data will be send to the server side (c++ program). In the server program date and time will be applied to the system as below:

```
int main(){
    string date = "2013-08-28T00:00:00";
    string newtime = "09:12";
    time_t mytime = time(0);
      struct tm* tm_ptr = localtime(&mytime);

      if (tm_ptr)
      {
        tm_ptr->tm_mon  = atoi(date.substr(5,2).c_str()) - 1;
        tm_ptr->tm_mday = atoi(date.substr(8,2).c_str());
        tm_ptr->tm_year = atoi(date.substr(0,4).c_str());
        tm_ptr->tm_min  = atoi(newtime.substr(3,2).c_str());
        tm_ptr->tm_hour  = atoi(newtime.substr(0,2).c_str());
        printf("%d\n%d\n%d\n%d\n%d\n", tm_ptr->tm_mon,tm_ptr->tm_mday,tm_ptr->tm_year,tm_ptr->tm_min,tm_ptr->tm_hour);
        const struct timeval tv = {mktime(tm_ptr), 0};
        settimeofday(&tv, 0);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

But when running this code system crashes!
I have another code for applying date and time:

```
int main(){
    string date = "2013-08-28T00:00:00";
    string newtime = "09:12";
    string newdate = "";
    string monthnum = date.substr(5,2);
    string month = "";
    if(strcmp(monthnum.c_str(),"01") == 0)         month = "Jan";
    else if(strcmp(monthnum.c_str(),"02") == 0)     month = "Feb";
    else if(strcmp(monthnum.c_str(),"03") == 0)     month = "Mar";
    else if(strcmp(monthnum.c_str(),"04") == 0)     month = "Apr";
    else if(strcmp(monthnum.c_str(),"05") == 0)     month = "May";
    else if(strcmp(monthnum.c_str(),"06") == 0)     month = "Jun";
    else if(strcmp(monthnum.c_str(),"07") == 0)     month = "Jul";
    else if(strcmp(monthnum.c_str(),"08") == 0)     month = "Aug";
    else if(strcmp(monthnum.c_str(),"09") == 0)     month = "Sep";
    else if(strcmp(monthnum.c_str(),"10") == 0)     month = "Oct";
    else if(strcmp(monthnum.c_str(),"11") == 0)     month = "Nov";
    else if(strcmp(monthnum.c_str(),"12") == 0)     month = "Dec";
    newdate = "\"" + month + " " + date.substr(8,2) + " " + date.substr(0,4) + " " + newtime + "\"";
    system("date --set newdate");
    return 0;
}
```

when running this code an error was occurred as below:
date: invalid date "newdate"

I can't understand the problem of these codes!

Comment: For the crash, run your program in a debugger. For the `newdate` problem, think about how you would otherwise put the value of a variable into a string.

Comment: Setting date as result of user input sounds like recipe for disaster. Please consider configuring NTP properly

Comment: Please, step away from the keyboard.

Comment: Are you sure you have enough privileges to set the system time.  Normal users don't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "invalid date" part is because it actually executes "date --set newdate".  You want it to execute "date --set [value of newdate variable]".

---

Change

```
system("date --set newdate");
```

to

```
string cmd = "date --set ";
cmd += newdate;
system(cmd.c_str());
```

Comment: Wouldn't that make into into a `std::string`? Remember that `system` takes an old C-style string.

Comment: That might be correct - I'm obviously a bit rusty.  Will try to dig out correct syntax.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Thanks. Changed to something that actually works when I try to compile and run it.

Comment: What's wrong with just `system( ("date --set " + newdate).c_str() );`?

Comment: @JamesKanze: If you can use real API, it is almost always really bad idea to use `system()`. If you call external command, you might just as well not use C in first place.

Comment: @mvp I totally agree.  I was just commenting the solution proposed above.  In practice, I'd try and determine why the OP's solution using `settimeofday` wasn't working.

Comment: system(cmd.c_str()) outputs the date.Is it possible to avoid system output?

Answer (score 0):

`sprintf` can be another option...

```
sprintf(newdate,"date --set %s %s %s %s", month, date.substr(8,2), date.substr(0,4), newtime);
system(newdate);
```

just check if the variable is of type `string` or upur platform support `sprintf`.